Proving inequality containing sum over binomials
I'm trying to prove the following statement:
Show that for every $d>4$ there is a $c>0 $ such that for all $n \geq 1$
$$
  \sum_{k = 2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1}2^{-k}\sum_{l = 0}^{k}\binom{k}{l}l^{-d/2} \leq c2^{-\tfrac{d-2}{2}n}.
$$
There are several ways I've tried already. Namely

splitting the second sum into $l = 0,1$ and $l \geq2$ and arguing, that $l^{-d/2}\leq 2^{-d/2}$ for $l \geq2$. Next we can take $2^{-d/2}$ out of the sum. Then we know that the sum over the binomials is equal to $2^k$. But this can't work, as term $l = 1$ gives us $2^{n-1-d/2}$ which already dominates what we want.
bounding $l^{-d/2}$ by the next bigger power of $\frac{1}{2}$ which turns out to be something like the following $$\sum_{l = 0}^{k}l^{d/2} \leq \sum_{l = 0}^{{n-1}}2^l2^{-dl/2} = \sum_{l = 0}^{{n-1}}2^{-\tfrac{d-2}{2}l} $$ and looks very promising. But if i estimate the binomial by it's largest value, i.e. $2^{k-1}$ it is again not dominating the left hand side (or that is at least what wolfram alpha tells me).

Any other ideas?

What is $d$? A positive integer? Or a negative integer? (Did you miss out negative signs in point 1?)

Thanks @CalvinLin .Yes, I seem to have forgotten the minuses. Supposedly this holds for all real numbers $d>0$. But what I need to work with is only the case $d>4$.
